# C++ Win32 - Tracking ListView items for private chat

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

Alright so what I am doing is creating a encrypted chat room for my friends and I to mess around in.

I wanted to make a private chat where you could right click their name on the List View and message them.

Currently I a structure with all "users" information like name, time logged on, and List View Number. But that List View number becomes incorrect when a user disconnects because it shifts everyone down by one.

How would I be able to essentially "tie" a user to a List View item? That way no matter how many people log on / off when I click on their name it will PM that person. (I tried to use LVN_ITEMCHANGE because I thought the iItem would change but it didn't to my experiance)

**My Idea*
My Idea was to add a random character field in the ListView item called "token" that way when someone clicks on the name it will find the "token" that would be unique and do it that way. But maybe their is an easier way so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data structure should not be tracking the ListView items **at all**.  It is just extra data.

Your ListView can associate each list item with a data structure.  The [`LVITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) structure has an `lParam` field for handling user-defined values:

- When you want to add a new user to the ListView, dynamically allocate your data structure and assign that pointer to the `LVITEM::lParam` field before using the [`LVM_INSERTITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107.aspx) message.
- When you want to access a particular user's data, retrieve that list item's `LVITEM` using the [`LVM_GETITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953.aspx) message, and then type-cast its `lParam` to access your data structure.
- When you want to remove a user, simply remove that list item using the [`LVM_DELETEITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774895.aspx) message, and then use the [`LVN_DELETEITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774812.aspx) notification to free the associated data structure.

Alternatively, use the ListView in virtual mode via the [`LVS_OWNERDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx) window style (see [Virtual List-View Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style) and [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx)), and then you don't need to use the `LVITEM::lParam` field at all.  Store your data structures in a separate array/container somewhere off to the side, and then use the [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818.aspx) notification to provide display data to the ListView only when it needs data.  When you add/remove users from your array/container, simply use the [`LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761188.aspx) message to update the ListView's item count to match the new array/container count.  That way there is always a direct relation between ListView items and container items. Let `LVN_GETDISPINFO` tell you which array/container item to access.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me a whole new perspective.